# Multiple Solutions for Law of Cosine?

Tags: trigonometry

I think I have started to overthink things....

I am trying to solve both SSS and SAS triangles with Law of Cosines.
For SSS, I first find the angle which could be obtuse and then use the Law of Sines to find the next angle.

For SAS, I first find the missing side length using Law of Cosines and then use the Law of Sines to find another angle.

I also try to answer problems completely using Law of Cosine, or sometimes trying to find the other angle with Law of Sines.

With all these different methods, I keep getting different answers for each solution path.  Usually they are very minor (I'm rounding to 3 decimals so I'm no too worried about being a thousandth off).  But in some cases, there are some big differences in the answers I get.

Is this possible? or is there a certain way you should be solving these triangles so that there is only one correct solution?

For example, consider $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle B=88^{\circ}, a=4.4,c=5.2$ where I got side $b=6.694$ by Law of Cosines and then the following angle solutions using different methods:

1. finding $\angle A=41.064^{\circ}$ using Law of Sines and then finding $\angle C=50.936^{\circ}$.  I also got these solutions by using Law of Cosines to find angle A as a second step.
2. finding $\angle C=50.927^{\circ}$ using Law of Sines and then finding $\angle A=41.073^{\circ}$.  I also got these solutions by using Law of Cosines to find angle C as a second step.

Comment: Are you rounding your intermediate results? The amount of error you are getting isn't too surprising if you are.

Comment: with each thing I find I round to three decimals.  Does it still make sense that I get different answers with different methods though?

Comment: Yes, the inverse trig functions are fairly sensitive to the precision. If you calculate one more decimal point for $b$, the two results should match.